# ERROR: 8 - CURL error: couldn't connect to host in infusionsoft apit

Tags: php, api

I am using the php isdk to fetch the data from the infusionsoft.It is showing the connectivity with the infusionsoft but when I write the dsQuery function for fetch the data it is displaying the 'ERROR: 8 - CURL error: couldn't connect to host' errors.How can I resolve it.

```
    include_once("iSDK/iSDK/isdk/isdk.php");
    include_once("iSDK/iSDK/isdk/xmlrpc-3.0/lib/xmlrpc.inc");
    $myApp = new iSDK;
    if ($myApp->cfgCon("m168")) {
    echo "Connected...";
    } else {
    die("Failed to connect to Infusionsoft!");
     }
    $returnFields = array('Id','FirstName');
    $query = array('FirstName' => 'Alan');
    $contacts = $myApp->dsQuery("Contact",10,0,$query,$returnFields);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($contacts);
    echo "</pre>";
```

the output is:

Connected...

ERROR: 8 - CURL error: couldn't connect to host

Answer (score 0):

I would check to make sure you have the latest version of the SDK. Double check your API key as well.